# MySQL check if datetime column is within weekend period

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with a datetime column in the database. Is there a way i can write my query to determine if the record is within the weekend period?

I want to display all records and have an additional column in each result row to display Weekend if it meets the criteria of (after Friday 1730hours) or (before sunday 2359hours).

The below is what I currently have but something seems to be wrong. :( any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

```
SELECT recordTime, DATE_FORMAT(recordTime, "%W %w %T"), (( (DATE_FORMAT(recordTime, "%T") > '17:30:00' AND DAYOFWEEK(recordTime)=6)
    AND (DATE_FORMAT(recordTime, "%T") < '23:59:59' AND DAYOFWEEK(recordTime)=7) )
    OR (DATE_FORMAT(recordTime, "%T") < '23:59:59' AND DAYOFWEEK(recordTime)=0)) AS Weekend
FROM `waitrecord`
```

Comment: query seems wrong: shouldn't the oreder of statements be: SELECT .... FROM table WHERE .... AND .... OR

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. A day cannot be weekday 6 and weekday 7 at the same time.

The condition should be

```
DAYOFWEEK(recordTime) = 7
or DAYOFWEEK(recordTime) = 1
or (DATE_FORMAT(recordTime, "%T") > '17:30:00' AND DAYOFWEEK(recordTime) = 6)
```

*Edit:* [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) actually returns `1` for Sunday and `7` for Saturday (in contrast to [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) which is zero based)

Comment: got it. this works great except the index starts with 1 for Sunday and not 0. but what i need works now. thanks so much!

Comment: according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format, sunday is 0...

Comment: but saturday is 6, so there's a typo.

Comment: DAYOFWEEK(recordTime) IN(1, 7)

Comment: `DAYOFWEEK` is one-based and 1 = Sunday.`WEEKDAY` is zero-based and 0 = Monday.